# No "Apply" button when attempting to duplicate an administrator menu

Tags: administrator, menu

I tried to duplicate an administrator menu, but this is not possible due to a missing "apply" button.

Is there any settings or circumstances where this can happen?

I recorded a little gif to demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

Comment: I found this issue on the Joomla Tracker: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/22178 which looks as if it's relevant. And there are some other issues on the same topic. I think it's because you've got an unpublished menu item there. If you click on Search Tools and then set the status search box to Published and then try and do the batch operation the button appears ok. But when I leave the search box empty and just select published menuitems it still doesn't work. It looks as if there's still some bug in Joomla there so you might want to raise an issue on the tracker.

Comment: Yeah could be that too @RobbieJackson. The first thing I thought of was the button is missing in the `default_batch_footer.php` file.

Comment: @RobbieJackson this worked for me, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the file `default_batch_footer.php` in `/administrator/components/your-component/views/your-view/tmpl/`
2. Open the file.
3. Add this code:

   ```
       <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('your-view.batch');">
           <?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_BATCH_PROCESS'); ?>
       </button>
   ```

   **(rename your-view with the name of your view)**
4. Save the file.